# Scaling a ruby script to store data in MySQL using sidekiq?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I have a script that works fine on a few thousand records and I am starting to learn sidekiq to help run it on millions of records periodically.

I have two tables; a table full of auto parts and another table with sales stats in it. I access sales stats via an API provided by the company, my script grabs a line from the auto parts table and requests data from the parts stats API and stores it in another table used for reporting alongside another dataset.

What I am wondering is, when using sidekiq, what would be the best way to flag records in my auto parts table to know that they have been processed?

I figure that a simple flagging with a 1 or 0 could work but adding a last modified_date or added_date is probably more effective?

Which option would be best to process all records as quickly as possible  using Ruby, Sidekiq and MySQL?

I know that running into insert issues is MySQL is one thing that we have been looking into but would love some advice or links to help us out.

I hope all is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like it could be done in 1 insert statement, bypassing all that other architecture. `INSERT INTO report_helper SELECT ... FROM auto_parts JOIN stats ...`

Answer (score 0):

> I figure that a simple flagging with a 1 or 0 could work but adding a last modified_date or added_date is probably more effective?

You're micro-optimizing here. Prematurely, I might add.

> I access sales stats via an API provided by the company

Any possible performance gains from those SQL tweaks are nothing compared to cost of those API calls.